# How to use quotation mark in grep range query

Tags: grep

How to find `(f'` or `(f"` or `("` or `('` with grep?

For example the regex could be `(f\?["']` but how to pass this to grep - it can't be surrounded by quotation marks neither by apostrophes?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern in your question `f\?["']` matches an `f` char followed by `?` and one of `"` or `'`

If the text is for example in `file`, you might use:

```
grep -Eo "(\(|\bf)['\"]" file
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Start group

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `|` Or
  - `\bf` A word boundary followed by matching `f`
- `)` Close the group
- `['\"]` Match either `'` or `"`

Output

```
f'
f"
("
('
```